# Expand search bar full width bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am implementing a navigation bar with the elements in this order: 
LOGO      SEARCH-BAR       MENU       SIGN-IN.

I did achieve this using the following code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
<!--LOGO-->
            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#"> <img
                src="#" title="title" border="0">
            </a> <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">Brand
<!--SEARCH BAR-->
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">

                <div style="display: table;" class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"
                        placeholder="Search Here" name="search" style=""
                        class="form-control"> <span style="width: 1%;"
                        class="input-group-addon"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>

                </div>
            </form> 

        </div>

<!--MENU and SIGN--->
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
            id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a
                                href="#"></a></li>
                            <li><a
                                href="#"></a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">...</a></li>

                <li>
                    Sign in
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I changed my navbar collapse width to 990px by adding following CSS:

```
/* Navbar COLLAPSE at 990px instead of default 768 px*/

    @media ( max-width : 990px) {

        .navbar-header {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-left, .navbar-right {
            float: none !important;
        }
        .navbar-toggle {
            display: block;
        }
        .navbar-collapse {
            border-top: 1px solid transparent;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        }
        .navbar-fixed-top {
            top: 0;
            border-width: 0 0 1px;
        }
        .navbar-collapse.collapse {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .navbar-nav {
            float: none !important;
            margin-top: 7.5px;
        }
        .navbar-nav>li {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-nav>li>a {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .collapse.in {
            display: block !important;
        }

        /*width:auto for dropdowns to take full spacing between 768px and 990px. (Default takes full spacing below 768px)*/

        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
            position: static;
            float: none;
            width: auto;
            margin-top: 0;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        /* For dropdown eg: Categories to be listed centered. (Default left aligned) */

        .dropdown-menu {
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
```

I want SEARCH-BAR to take full width if there is space available.

This is happening for width less than `990px` (the media query I edited), but for greater than 990px the search bar does not occupy the full spacing. It's width is default size.

I guess I need to edit navbar-form for `990px` media query, but does not seem to make it work.

Any help is appreciated. I am new to styling.

Comment: Take advantage of the element viewer in your browser's developer tools.  You should be able to select the element you want to resize and look at the 'computed' values.  You can derive which style is causing the behavior you want to avoid, and change it accordingly.  For example in Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/?hl=en

Comment: @JoeEssey: Thanks. I inspected the element. I now know that the style needs to be applied on screens >990px only. But how to make search expand full, not able to figure out. `.navbar-form` already has `width:auto` applied to it. Any other insight you could make it expand?

Comment: You can either try an alternative to `.navbar-form`, or overwrite the part of that class's style definition so that its width is 100%.  You would do that by defining a css class and including its file after you include bootstrap's style resource.  Boostrap navbar styling can be a challenging experience, but stick with it.

Comment: After trying styles, it's feels when I give `navbar-header` a `float:none` my search bar expands full width pushing the menu go to next line. I want it to just take the space till it has empty space to the right. Any idea?